# Higher Resolution Screenshot for Print (Linux)

Tags: linux, screenshot

I am working on a Linux OS and need to **print a screenshot in a book** and therefore I need a software, which takes higher resolution screenshots (**at least 300 DPI**) than for example `GIMP` screenshot or `Gnome Screenshot` (both take them at 93 DPI). Are there alternatives or solutions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the -q (quality) flag with `scrot`, you will get an image with the full resolution of the screen.  The print resolution depends on the size at which you print the image.

Comment: Thanks! I think I need some software, that takes higher resolutions images than the resolution of the screen (maybe my monitor is too small?).

Comment: The only way to get a screenshot image with higher resolution than the screen is for the software to invent data--e.g, by interpolating.  A variety of graphic processing tools will do this, but I daresay you won't find it in any screenshot tool.  (Or, as you say, get a higher-resolution screen.)